# Element UI Change text color of el-radio

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vue-cli, element-ui

i need to change default of :checked text color to red #f10606

```js
var Main = {
    data () {
      return {
        formradio: ''
      };
    }
  }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.4.3/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
.el-radio__input.is-checked+.el-radio__label {
     color: #f10606;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
  <el-radio-group v-model="formradio">
     <el-radio label="option1">  Option 1  </el-radio>
     <el-radio label="option2">  Option 2  </el-radio>
   </el-radio-group>
   
   
</template>
</div>
```

but i try this style it not work

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
 .el-radio__input.is-checked+.el-radio__label {
     color: #f10606;
 }
```

this style i have inspect from chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use `!important`:

```css
.el-radio__input.is-checked + .el-radio__label {
   color: #000000 !important;
}
```

or use a more specific selector, for example by putting a class on the group:

```html
<el-radio-group v-model="form-radio" class="myradiogroup">
    <el-radio label="option1">  Option 1  </el-radio>
    <el-radio label="option2">  Option 2  </el-radio>
</el-radio-group>
```

```css
.myradiogroup .el-radio__input.is-checked + .el-radio__label {
  color: #000000;
}
```

If the issue is with scoped styles, use a deep `>>>` or `::v-deep` selector:

```css
>>> .el-radio__input.is-checked + .el-radio__label {
   color: #000000;
}
```